# How do I permanently recover from grub rescue?

Tags: boot, partition, grub2, dual-boot, move-partition

This question relates to a Windows/Linux dual boot system on a DOS-partitioned SSD (i.e. none with GPT/UEFI). Originally, the computer only had Windows 10 on an HDD. Then I managed to transfer this system to the SSD, resize the partitions and install Xubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10, and it all worked fine.

There always was an EFI partition on the drive. I don't know what it is good for since this is not an UEFI device. But I did not change this partition. - There is no swap partition on this system.

I wanted to create more space for my Linux system partition. To be more flexible in case the requirements change later, I moved the Windows home partition between the two Linux partitions. The partition layout looks like this now:

```
NAME   FSTYPE PARTTYPE PARTFLAGS LABEL
sda                              
├─sda1 ntfs   0x7      0x80      System-reserviert
├─sda2 ntfs   0x7                SSD-Windows-Sys
├─sda3 vfat   0xef               SSD-EFI
├─sda4        0x5                
├─sda6 ext4   0x83               SSD-Linux-Sys
├─sda5 ntfs   0x7                SSD-Windows-Home
└─sda7 ext4   0x83               SSD-Linux-Home
```

(sda-numbers not strictly ascending, the partitions are shown **in SSD-storage order** sda6-sda5-sda7.)

I did not alter any of the partitions 1 to 3. I succeeded to maintain the original UUIDs and LABELs using `gparted` to move and resize the ntfs partition SSD-Windows-Home. There is no equivalent to `tune2fs -U <UUID>` for vfat and ntfs and I did not want to exchange the serial numbers by fiddeling with `dd` as proposed in [this discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406426/how-to-change-uuid-of-ntfs-partition), therefore I did it with resizing and moving the ntfs-partition `SSD-Windows-Home`.

For the Linux partitions, I used `gparted` to create an new ext4 partition at the end of the SSD, `rsync` to copy the contents from the old to the new partition, then I deleted the old one and resized the other partitions to fill the gaps. Finally I applied `tune2fs` to achieve the shown state, especially in maintaining the same LABELs and UUIDs for all partitions as they were before all this.

During the partition change work, I encountered a warning that boot problems might show up after my changes. I did not care, since the LABELs and the UUIDs for each partition remained the same. **But this was a keen assumption, as I had to notice, when I tried to reboot:**

The boot process stopped in `grub rescue>`  rather than in the GRUB2 menu asking me which operating system to boot.

I succeeded to boot the computer by issuing these commands:

```
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,6)/boot/grub
grub rescue> set root=(hd0,6)/
grub rescue> insmod linux
grub rescue> insmod normal
grub rescue> normal
```

Then the GRUB2 menu was shown and I could select between Linux and Windows 10. **Both operating systems worked as before all my partition changes** (of course I had to shut down the computer in between and go through `grub rescue>`  again).

I was advised to run the following command after booting into the Linux system in order to permanently recover from the `grub rescue` problem:

```
$LC_ALL=C sudo grub-install --target=/boot/grub/i386-pc /dev/sda
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
$
```

There is a file `/boot/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh` (and there are two more of them in `/boot/grub/x86_64-efi` and in `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi`).

Therefore I have tried

```
$LC_ALL=C sudo grub-install --target=/boot/grub/i386-pc /dev/sda6
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/boot/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
$
```

It searches in the wrong directory. Therefore I have added `--directory=/boot/grub/i386-pc`:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sudo grub-install --directory=/boot/grub/i386-pc /dev/sda6
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: cannot open `/boot/grub/i386-pc/moddep.lst': No such file or directory.
$ ls -l /boot/grub/i386-pc/moddep.lst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5416 2019-12-10 10:34 /boot/grub/i386-pc/moddep.lst
$
```

As you can see from the `ls` command, this error message is definitely wrong, because `/boot/grub/i386-pc/moddep.lst` exists and root can also access it! Now I'm at the end of my wits.

After the computer was able to start with the `grub rescue` commands (rather than from a live stick and using `chroot`), it shouldn't be that difficult to permanently apply exactly the information I entered, but without having to enter it on each boot process.

**How do you do this correctly?**

Comment: For target `i386-pc` you have to specify only the *disk* not the *partition*: `sudo grub-install --target=/boot/grub/i386-pc /dev/sda` not `sdaX`.

Comment: ```sudo grub-install --target=/boot/grub/i386-pc /dev/sda``` gives me the same error message ```grub-install: Fehler: /usr/lib/grub/boot/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh existiert nicht. Bitte geben Sie --target oder --directory an```

Comment: This is a 64-Bit computer. There is no directory ```/usr/lib/grub/boot/grub/i386-pc```. There are ```/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi``` and ```/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed```. In the former there is a file ```modinfo.sh```, in the latter there is no file with such a name.

Comment: Run `LC_ALL=C sudo grub-install --target=/boot/grub/i386-pc /dev/sda` so you can share (or lookup) the error in english. It's possible that you need to install the grub package for `i386-pc`. [This Arch's wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Master_Boot_Record_(MBR)_specific_instructions) has more information that can be helpful.

Comment: the result is ```grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/boot/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.```

Comment: [Here's a solution](https://devicetests.com/fix-grub-2-install-error). You may need to install the `grub-pc` and or `grub-pc-bin` package.

Comment: Concerning the ArchWiki link: In my case, the gap before the first partition is 1MiB. It worked that way before the partition work.

Comment: Neither ```grub-pc```, nor ```grub-pc-bin``` nor ```grub-efi``` are installed on my pc. I'll look at Brent Cohen's solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi` and `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed` indicates that the Xubuntu was installed as an UEFI-booting system, suggesting that your system is in fact UEFI-capable.

The fact that your `sda` disk includes a Windows installation and is partitioned in MBR style indicates your Windows must boot using the classic BIOS style. To achieve the ability to easily choose the OS to boot from the GRUB menu, you would want Xubuntu to boot in legacy BIOS style too. But it appears the packages required for legacy-style GRUB are not currently installed in your system.

You said `grub-efi` is not installed on your system: such a package does not exist on Debian/Ubuntu. The UEFI equivalent of `grub-pc` is named `grub-efi-amd64`. The name `grub-pc` is legacy from when GRUB used to be an x86/BIOS-only bootloader; now it supports many other architectures and firmware types.

The commands suggested in the comments had some typos: the `--target` option of `grub-install` does not take a pathname, but a GRUB platform identifier: in your case, `i386-pc`.

First, install the legacy BIOS support packages for GRUB:

```
sudo apt install grub-pc grub-pc-bin
```

Then, install GRUB into the Master Boot Record of the system:

```
sudo grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sda
```

Check the contents of `/etc/default/grub`. If there is a line

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

you may want to change it to `false`, make sure the `os-prober` package is installed, and then run `sudo update-grub` to create a GRUB configuration that includes both your OSs.

Then mount `sda3` and inspect its contents:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
sudo ls -l /mnt
```

If it includes an `EFI` directory, rename it to something else (in case your system firmware has uncontrollable preference towards UEFI booting):

```
sudo mv /mnt/EFI /mnt/NO-EFI
sudo umount /mnt
```

Now it's time to reboot. After verifying that you can now successfully boot both your operating systems, you can remove the UEFI boot support packages with:

```
sudo apt purge grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed efibootmgr shim-signed shim-helpers-amd64-signed shim-signed-common
```

Comment: *"The commands suggested in the comments had some typos"*, oh yes, I blindly copied and pasted and didn't spot that.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, which not only shows what to do, but also why. It worked like a charm! - When deleting at the very end,``` shim-helpers-amd64-signed``` and ```shim-signed-common``` didn't exist for me, so I ran the command again like this: ```sudo apt purge grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed efibootmgr shim-signed```

Then there was a message that the directory ```/usr/lib/shim``` is not empty. **Can I still delete it and its contents?**

Comment: It should be safe to delete. The packaging of the Secure Boot shim varies a bit by Debian/*Ubuntu version, and I included all the package names I knew for the sake of completeness. Since Secure Boot is applicable only to UEFI-style boot, and you are now fully in legacy BIOS mode, you won't need anything Secure Boot-related. You can also remove the `sda3` partition... unless you want to keep the possibility to (relatively easily) convert to UEFI, of course.